# Export GCP Datastore and import to a different GCP Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to copy data from DataStore in one GCP project to another - the process doesn't seem to give any errors, but also doesn't populate my target datastore.

In my source project I create a bucket and export my datastore in to it as follows :

```
gcloud datastore export gs://ctb_datatransfer
```

I then switch to my destination project and run

```
gcloud datastore import gs://ctb_datatransfer/2020-03-01T18:41:37_32872/2020-03-01T18:41:37_32872.overall_export_metadata
```

Neither of these steps seem to indicate any errors, but my destination datastore remains empty after the import has completed.

Any help is gratefully received as I don't really have much of a clue about what is happening - I believe that I have granted the correct permissions on the bucket ( and would expect to see some sort of permissions failure if I hadn't I guess )

The output from the export step looks like this

```
    done: true
metadata:
  "@type": type.googleapis.com/google.datastore.admin.v1.ExportEntitiesMetadata
  common:
    endTime: "2020-03-01T18:41:50.349159Z"
    operationType: EXPORT_ENTITIES
    startTime: "2020-03-01T18:41:37.188012Z"
    state: SUCCESSFUL
  entityFilter: {}
  outputUrlPrefix: gs://ctb_datatransfer/2020-03-01T18:41:37_32872
  progressBytes:
    workCompleted: "8848"
    workEstimated: "6480"
  progressEntities:
    workCompleted: "40"
    workEstimated: "40"
name: projects/chattyappsdata-staging/operations/ASAzMTEwMzAzMTMJGnRsdWFmZWQHEjJ3LXVlLXNib2otbmltZGEQCigS
response:
  "@type": type.googleapis.com/google.datastore.admin.v1.ExportEntitiesResponse
```

while the output from the import step looks like this

```
    done: true
metadata:
  "@type": type.googleapis.com/google.datastore.admin.v1.ImportEntitiesMetadata
  common:
    endTime: "2020-03-01T18:46:25.251008Z"
    operationType: IMPORT_ENTITIES
    startTime: "2020-03-01T18:45:44.029056Z"
    state: SUCCESSFUL
  entityFilter: {}
  inputUrl: gs://ctb_datatransfer/2020-03-01T18:41:37_32872/2020-03-01T18:41:37_32872.overall_export_metadata
  progressBytes:
    workCompleted: "8110"
    workEstimated: "8848"
  progressEntities:
    workCompleted: "40"
    workEstimated: "40"
name: projects/chattytoolbox/operations/AiAwNTEwNDAxMTMJGnRsdWFmZWQHEjJ3LXVlLXNib2otbmltZGEQCigS
response:
  "@type": type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Empty
```

Comment: How are you testing for an empty datastore?  Are you looking in the cloud console for chattytoolbox?

Comment: @JimMorrison - yes - just refreshing the console page and it tells the the database is empty

Comment: @JimMorrison - actually - and wierdly - I've just checked it now ( after not doing anything for 24 hours or so ) and the entities have now appeared in the destination datastore.

Comment: @DaveH Is the issue solved now?

Comment: @Ajordat - well, the data now exists in the destination datasource but it seemed to appear without me doing anything. I don;t know if this is just an artefact of the GCP datastore console, but it seemed like the immediately after I did the imprt the console told me the database was empty, and then when I checked again several hours later, the data had appeared. I don't understand why or how that happened.

Comment: The command `gcloud datastore import` can use the argument [`--async`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/datastore/import#--async), is it possible that you used it? This would've created the operation and returned immediately without finishing, doing it hours later.

Comment: @Ajordat - thanks for your response - I didn't supply the `--async` flag

Comment: @DaveH - Looking at the documentation about importing entities, I've found that the import is a [long running operation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#long-running-operation) and thus it may take a substantial amount of time to complete. From the import output you shared, we can see that the operation [did finish](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#estimating_the_completion_time), but I believe it was missing some propagation, which got fixed by time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by OP in the comments, the whole process ended up working, it just did it hours later. This is a possible explanation:

Looking at the documentation about importing entities, I've found that the import is a [long running operation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#long-running-operation) (LRO) and thus it may take a substantial amount of time to complete. From the import output you shared, we can see that the operation [did finish](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#estimating_the_completion_time), but I believe it was missing some propagation, which got fixed by time.

Also, the import command (`gcloud datastore import`) it just starts the LRO. If you specify the argument [`--async`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/datastore/import#--async) the command will return immediately but if you don't, it will wait for a response. On [this section](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#importing_specific_kinds_or_namespaces), on the gcloud tab, it's stated that even if the import command gets cancelled the operation will continue, thus reinforcing the theory about the independence of the command, the import and the propagation.

Comment: I had the same issue and came to this post.
I understand it's a long running operation (LRO) and it takes some time, but in my case when I ran command 'gcloud datastore operations describe ******', after some time it showed  'state SUCCESSFULL'. 
At this time I expected the data to show up on the datastore view, but it still says datastore empty. Is it tipical to take some time after the process has ended to show the data? It seems a bit strange behavior.

Comment: Just an update, while it was still not showing on the datastore view, I created a dummy Entity 'Test'. This showed the view 'QUERY BY KIND', where it lists only 'Test' entity. In here, I manually typed one of the entity that I restored, then magically it showed the data! It seems the UI is not in synch with the actual data that exists. This is not corrected event when 'Refresh' is clicked. I guess this is one of the quirkiness of the datastore? Not liking it.