# How to copy a GCP Datastore Entity to another project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to copy the data from my User_Log kind from my Test GCP project to my Live project. I have exported the User_Log kind from the Datastore to the Google Cloud Storage bucket for the Test project. But when I go to import it using the GCP GUI into the Live project I can't see the Test project buckets - even though I have given Storage Admin access to testProject@appspot.gserviceaccount.com in my Live project and vice versa Storage Admin access to LiveProject@appspot.gserviceaccount.com in the Test project.

From what I have read it should be possible to transfer files from one project's bucket to another.
Thanks
TimN

Comment: Did you try to fill in manually the full path of your export? the full path, is the Cloud Storage path with the `gs://` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can't import/export from one project to another using the GCP Console GUI, but you can if you use gcloud using the commands in the post: [Export GCP Datastore and import to a different GCP Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60479107/export-gcp-datastore-and-import-to-a-different-gcp-project)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the Cloud Console UI only allows you to select the buckets that exist in you current project. However, if the *overall_export_metadata* file is located in another project, you'll have to use other methods like gcloud tool or REST for the import - [link](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#importing_all_entities)